# Passing user credentials from Flow to Microsoft Graph

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

Has anyone had success passing user credentials to the Microsoft Graph from a Microsoft Flow? There are Planner attributes I want to pull back that aren't available in the Planner connector. It appears that the MS Flow http connector only supports OAUTH authentication for registered applications, not OAUTH user authentication.

I'd like for the Flow to be able to access the Microsoft Graph with my user AD credentials. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Flows execute without an interactive user, there is no opportunity to prompt you to authenticate. This is why you're limited to the Client Credentials OAuth flow, it doesn't require user authentication.

Comment: that was my assumption--just thought someone have identified a workaround.